# WiFi problems on Yosemite

Tags: macos, network, wifi, crash

I've seen a few posts around wifi problems with Yosemite, especially after an update from Mavericks. I've only started seeing WiFi problems about 3 days ago (update was 3-6 months ago), and my issues are happening on a number of routers.

Looking on the console, I see a number of the following messages:

```
> 06/06/2015 17:07:03.691 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
> 06/06/2015 17:07:04.443 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
> 06/06/2015 17:07:07.277 com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[2260]: dnssd_clientstub write_all(16) failed -1/64 32 Broken pipe
> 06/06/2015 17:07:07.277 com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[2260]: dnssd_clientstub write_all(16) failed -1/28 32 Broken pipe
> 06/06/2015 17:07:19.113 discoveryd[2360]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 8.8.8.8 Port 53 errno 65, fd 53, ErrLogCount 1 ResolverIntf:0
> 06/06/2015 17:07:19.114 discoveryd[2360]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 8.8.8.8 Port 53 errno 65, fd 51, ErrLogCount 2 ResolverIntf:0
> 06/06/2015 17:07:19.477 discoveryd[2360]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 8.8.4.4 Port 53 errno 65, fd 52, ErrLogCount 3 ResolverIntf:0
> 06/06/2015 17:07:20.177 discoveryd[2360]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 8.8.4.4 Port 53 errno 65, fd 37, ErrLogCount 4 ResolverIntf:0
> 06/06/2015 17:07:20.178 discoveryd[2360]: Basic DNSResolver UDNS Send(): UDP Sendto() failed to DNSNameServer 8.8.4.4 Port 53 errno 65, fd 37, ErrLogCount 5 ResolverIntf:0
```

WiFi otherwise "appears" normal (wifi symbol in the status bar shows no error, and network config says I'm still connected); however, no connectivity (not even through `ping`).

I can at this point disconnect and reconnect to the wifi, which will work for about 1 minute before disconnecting again.

Only long-term solution is to reboot. Unsure what triggers it!

I've tried, but no luck with,
- restart `discoveryd`
- clear safari cache
- change dns servers

Help would be appreciated - I'd rather avoid having to fresh-install the OS!

Answer (score 1):

The latest OS X 10.10.4 public beta, build 14E26a, totally gets rid of discoveryd. Go to [this Apple link](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram) and sign up for the public beta program, where you'll be given a link to download a piece of software that'll get the App Store to pick up beta updates. Take a backup of everything, install Beta Access Utility, and then install and enjoy a discoveryd-free Yosemite!

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is recent it might not be Yosemite related but Apple has [acknowledged](http://Apple%20Replaces%20Problematic%20'Discoveryd'%20Process%20With%20mDNSresponder%20in%2010.10.4%20Beta%204) the serious problems with the DNS using the discoveryd.

From the log it shows having problems with your DNS setting.

You use the Google public which should be fine but:

- Try changing it to 8.8.4.4 (and delete all other entries)
- Or even better:

Get this smart app and it will analyze and recommend to you the best and the fastest DNS in your location.

It is called "[namebench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/)".

- If you want more Surgical approach (without 10.10.4 (beta)

[Restoring mDNSResponder, if you dare](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/)

> First a word of warning: if something goes wrong, your Mac may not be
>   able to boot. This can be fixed by booting in single user mode and
>   re-enabling discoveryd (see below). Be sure you have a recent backup
>   just in case, and only follow the steps below if you are prepared to
>   boot into single user mode if needed.
>
> The first thing you need to do is find copies of 10.9 mDNSResponder,
>   mDNSResponderHelper, and their plist files. On a 10.9 system, they're
>   found in /usr/sbin/ and /System/Library/LaunchDaemons,
>   respectively.......

Disclaimer: I have not tested it since I am still on Mavericks.

Comment: Sure -- I've tried chaining the DNS config around, without much luck. Will try restoring the mDNS. Thanks!